# request for member 'setLogin' in 'giveData' which is of non-class type 'RegData()'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on car sharing project. So, I've done login and registration, after login the main menu is opening. In main menu I need to output a balance of an account. I do like this:

mainwindow.h

```
#include <...>
using namespace std;
class RegData;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    RegData givedata(); // the object of class from which I will get balance and output it in main menu
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
//... simple ui namespace

};
class RegData
{
private:
    QString login;
    QString email;
    QString password;
    int balance;
public:
    RegData(QString log = "", QString mail = "", QString pass = "", int bal=0) : login(log), email(mail), password(pass), balance(bal)
    {
    }
    void output()
    {
        qDebug() << login<<email<<password<<balance;
    }
    QString getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }
    QString getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    QString getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    void setLogin(QString log)
    {
        login = log;
    }
    void setEmail(QString mail)
    {
        email = mail;
    }
    void setPassword(QString pass)
    {
        password = pass;
    }
    void setBalance(int balanc)
    {
        balance = balanc;
    }
};
```

Ok, how I did registration:

1. Receiving data from file into QVector data;
2. Receiving data from login/pass lines etc.
3. If login hasn't registered yet, put the data into file

So, there are a part of code in login system. The part checks is account registered. If yes, I change data in object of RegData class 'givedata' and others

```
for(QVector<RegData>::iterator it = data.begin(); it<data.end(); it++)
            {
                if(loginline == it->getLogin() and passwordline == it->getPassword() or loginline == it->getEmail() and passwordline == it->getPassword())
                {
                    islog = true;
                    givedata.setLogin(loginline);
                    givedata.setEmail(it->getEmail());
                    givedata.setPassword(passwordline);
                    givedata.setBalance(it->getBalance());
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    islog = false;
                }
            }
```

The errors:

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\Carsharring_files\mainwindow.cpp:165: error: request for member 'setLogin' in 'givedata', which is of non-class type 'RegData()'
                     givedata.setLogin(loginline);
                              ^
```

and the same for setEmail, setBalance and setPassword.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is very exact: `givedata` is a function, that takes no parameters `()` and returns `RegData`, the function have no member `setLogin`. You definitely want to call it and work with the returned result.

```
givedata().setLogin(loginline);
givedata().setEmail(it->getEmail());
givedata().setPassword(passwordline);
givedata().setBalance(it->getBalance())
```

It will not solve all issues. Every call `givedata()` returns a new copy of an object and you apply setters to copies. The function should be declared to return a reference

```
RegData& givedata();
```